# Fluorination with xenon difluoride

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

Is this an error? Why is the nitro group reduced as the benzene ring is oxidized? I don't see any possible reducing agents here..

Also, what is the mechanism of aromatic fluorination by xenon difluoride? This appears analogous to electrophilic aromatic substitution in which benzene acts as a nucleophile and attacks an electrophile because of the expected meta-substitution pattern given the presence of the nitro group.

Is fluorine really electrophilic here? How so?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reaction as pictured above is incorrect, the nitro group is not reduced.  As you suggest this is (predominantly) an electrophilic aromatic substitution reaction.

Usually $\ce{HF}$ is used as a catalyst in these reactions and the following equilibrium is established.

$$\ce{XeF2 + HF <=> XeF+ + HF2^-}$$

The electrophilic $\ce{XeF^+}$ is the reactive species forming a complex with the aromatic ring.  Xenon is expelled from the complex and the reaction proceeds to yield the *meta*-fluoro isomer as expected for an electrophilic aromatic substitution.  Some other products, such as substituted biphenyls, are usually formed in small amounts suggesting that some minor pathway (radical-cation?) is also in play.